# Output from mediate function in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Im trying to inculde the output of the `mediate` function from mediation package in my RMarkdown (PDF) document. Using `summary` it gives me the table with the results from the bootstrapping analysis when I knitr the RMarkdown to a PDF document, but:

1. I don't like the look of the output and wuld like to have a more shiny table.
2. I can't lable this table with a caption and it's not included in the autmatic nummeration of RMarkdown (and as a consequence I can't reference it in the text).

I tried to use `kable` or `xtabs` with the output of the 'mediate` function but it won't work since both functions don't accept the class ("summary.mediate" "mediate") of the output.

This is how the code chunk in my RMarkdown document loks like:

````
```{r med.y1.z6.z7.c, echo = F, comment = "", strip.white = T, fig.cap="test"}

regDFM <- na.omit(as.data.frame(cbind(Y1, X1, Z1, Z6, Z7))) 
regFIT1.C.medY <- lm(Y1 ~ X1+Z1+Z6+Z7+X1:Z1, data = regDFM)
regFIT1.C.medM <- lm(Z7 ~ X1+Z1+Z6+X1:Z1, data = regDFM)
fitMED <- mediation::mediate(regFIT1.C.medM, regFIT1.C.medY, 
                         boot = T, sims = 10, treat="Z6", mediator="Z7")
summary(fitMED)

```
````

Any help or ideas are very appreciated!

Comment: You could look at the source code for `summary.mediate` and create your own summary function which just outputs the relevant information as a `data.frame`. Have a look at https://github.com/cran/mediation/blob/master/R/mediate.R#L1949

Comment: Thanks! That's sounds like a good and interesting but time consuming idea. If I find time I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With kable and the elements of the mediate function I finally created a nice RMarkdown > PDF output.

First I created a data.frame using the relevant elements of the mediate function (are the called 'elements'? what would yu call them?). Then just passing the data.frame to kable.

Thanks to @henrik_ibsen for the hint.

Here is my code:

```
regDFM <- na.omit(as.data.frame(cbind(Y1, X1, Z1, Z6, Z7))) 
regFIT1.C.medY <- lm(Y1 ~ X1+Z1+Z6+Z7+X1:Z1, data = regDFM)
regFIT1.C.medM <- lm(Z7 ~ X1+Z1+Z6+X1:Z1, data = regDFM)
fitMED <- mediation::mediate(regFIT1.C.medM, regFIT1.C.medY, 
                             boot = T, sims = 10, treat="Z6", mediator="Z7")

bt_effect <- c("Indirekter Effekt", "Direkter Effekt", "Gesamt Effekt", 
               "Anteil direkter Effekt")
bt_est <- c(fitMED$d1, fitMED$z1, fitMED$tau.coef, fitMED$n1)
#bt_p <- format.pval(c(fitMED$d1.p, fitMED$z1.p, fitMED$tau.p, fitMED$n1.p))
bt_p <- c(fitMED$d1.p, fitMED$z1.p, fitMED$tau.p, fitMED$n1.p)
bt_stars <- c(stars.pval(fitMED$d1.p), stars.pval(fitMED$z1.p),
              stars.pval(fitMED$tau.p), stars.pval(fitMED$n1.p))
bt_DF <- data.frame(row.names = bt_effect, format(bt_est, digits = 2), 
                    format(bt_p, nsmall = 3), bt_stars)
colnames(bt_DF) <- c("Koeffizienten", "p-Werte", "")

kable(bt_DF, booktabs = T, align = "c",
      caption = "Bootstraping-Analyse für Mediation") %>%
      footnote(general = c("Simulationen: 1000", "Signifikanzniveaus: ∗ p<0.05; 
                            ∗∗ p<0.01; ∗∗∗ p<0.001"),
               general_title = "Anmerkungen:")
```