# Export "mediate" output to LaTeX table

Tags: r, kable, xtable, texreg, modelsummary

I have a model summary from a `mediation::mediate` call, which I would like to export to LaTeX. Consider this example (from the documentation).

```
# install.packages("mediation")
library("mediation")
set.seed(2014)
data("framing", package = "mediation")
med.fit <- lm(emo ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = framing)
out.fit <- glm(cong_mesg ~ emo + treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = framing, family = binomial("probit"))
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit,   treat = "treat", mediator = "emo", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 100)
```

I would now like to export the `summary()` of `med.out` to a LaTeX table. (Importantly, all coefficients should be included!).

```
med.out %>% summary()
# Gives the following output:

# Causal Mediation Analysis 
# Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals
#                     Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
# ACME (control)             0.0791       0.0351         0.15  <2e-16 ***
# ACME (treated)             0.0804       0.0367         0.16  <2e-16 ***
# ADE (control)              0.0206      -0.0976         0.12    0.70    
# ADE (treated)              0.0218      -0.1053         0.12    0.70    
# Total Effect               0.1009      -0.0497         0.23    0.14    
# Prop. Mediated (control)   0.6946      -6.3109         3.68    0.14    
# Prop. Mediated (treated)   0.7118      -5.7936         3.50    0.14    
# ACME (average)             0.0798       0.0359         0.15  <2e-16 ***
# ADE (average)              0.0212      -0.1014         0.12    0.70    
# Prop. Mediated (average)   0.7032      -6.0523         3.59    0.14    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# Sample Size Used: 265 
# Simulations: 100
```

I tried the following which are all not (quite) working.

```
med.out %>% modelsummary::modelsummary() # produces output but misses coefficients
med.out %>% texreg::texreg() # produces error
med.out %>% xtable::xtable() # produces error
med.out %>% kableExtra::kable() # produces error
```

Does someone know of a smarter solution than getting the values from the object individually (e.g. `med.out$d1` etc.)?

**----EDIT----**

Similar questions do not answer this.

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695046/convert-the-summary-statistic-from-psych-package-mediate-function-to-latex) question refers to a different package providing a function of the same name (note that I am looking for the output of `mediation::mediate()`)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272687/output-from-mediate-function-in-rmarkdown) question extracts the values manually (using the above referenced way `med.out$d1`). I have a large number of models and even doing so with a custom function is not feasible, so I am looking for a more standardized solution.

Comment: If those duplicates don't work for you, please go into more detail about what exact errors you are getting or how the output doesn't match what you need.

Comment: @ivo the question is closed, but I opened an issue on Github. Feel free to comment there if my example does not help: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/604